# Not seeing the data return in Directive. How is it accessing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

so, I am trying to dive deep within angular and came across this code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/oNlZ8oRUk327R7yZH5k3?p=preview

Now, the idea behind it is moving away from controllers and trying to be more component based directive. See tut here:
https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/component-based-angularjs-directives

Anyways, the code in question is this:

```
ngModule.directive('multiplicationTable', [function() {
  return {
    templateUrl : 'multiplication-table-tpl.html',
    controllerAs : 'ctrl',
    transclude: true,
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {
      x : '=',
      y : '='
    },
    controller : function() {
      var x = this.x || 0;
      var y = this.y || 0;

      var table = this.rows = [];
      for(var i=0;i<y;i++) {
        var array = table[i] = [];
        for(var j=0;j<x;j++) {
          array.push(1); 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

and in the templateUrl, there is this:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in ctrl.rows track by $index">
  <div ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index">
    <div multiplication-cell
         x="$index+1"
         y="$parent.$index+1"
         ng-transclude>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, my question is -- where is "rows" being return or populated? I see an empty array assignment, but outside that - I do not see "this.rows" being populated nor returned... curious how the directive is manipulating and populating that object.

within the directive return scope, I do not see anything populating this.rows... how is the html getting it?

Answer (score 0):

From the code here:

```
var table = this.rows = [];
  for(var i=0;i<y;i++) {
    var array = table[i] = [];
    for(var j=0;j<x;j++) {
      array.push(1); 
    }
  }
```

you keep array "pointer" that points to  **table[i]** which points to **this.rows[i]** ;)
that way you alter this.rows when you do array.push(1).

From the directive "inputs" x and y that are bound on the element using = binding, you pass that information inside it. Since it is `bindToController:true`,  x and y are available on this.x and this.y instead of scope.x and scope.y.